# Scroll event lags in Chrome but not when dragging handlebar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angular

I am using

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
handleScroll(event) {
    this.scrollYPos = document.body.scrollTop;
}
```

to get the main scrollbar scroll position when it is scrolling and I am moving a div according to the scroll location.

When I use the mouse to scroll with the scrollwheel or if I press the scrollbar arrow buttons you can see there is a delay when the div is moving into position but I want it to look like it is stuck in position.
However if I drag the scrollbar handlebar I don't see this delay and the div is stuck like it should be.

Is the scroll event different when dragging the handlebar versus scrolling with the scrollbar arrow buttons or the mousewheel? Or how fast the event is propagated?

Please note in this scenario I am not able to use absolute or fixed position.
I am testing in latest Chrome...

UPDATE

This behavior is the same on Chrome and IE. Firefox however works well no matter where I scroll.

Comment: there is mousewheel, but it is not standard. In general, no there is not.